# Блокировка элементы Map на время проведения действия

Tags: java, map, синхронизация

Имеется `HashMap`, которая содержит список заказов. Может случиться так, что несколько потоков одновременно попробуют принять заказ.

Для того, чтобы избежать такой ситуации, я пытаюсь поставить блокировку на элемент списка (но не на весь список, чтобы не мешать чтению и аналогичной обработке других элементов):

```
Order order = map.get(id);

if (order != null && !order.isAccepted()) {
    synchronized (map.get(id)) {
        if (map.get(id) != null && !map.get(id).isAccepted()) {
            map.get(id).accept();
        }
    }
}
```

Сначала я достаю объект и провожу проверку требуемого условия на нем, чтобы он не стал `null` во время проверки условия. Затем я блокирую этот элемент в списке и повторно проверяю условие (оно могло измениться во время проверки первого условия), после чего производится действие.

---

Стоит ли использовать блокировку одного элемента, действительно ли это дает возможность работать с другими элементами, не блокируя список и не создает ли такая блокировка проблем (например, при удалении)?

Comment: Если `map.get(index)` внутри блока `synchronized` вернёт `null`, то дело кончится `NullPointerException`-ом. Если между `synchronized` и внутренним `if`-ом в `map` запишут другой объект по ключу `index` (странно, кстати, ключ называть индексом), то `accept` будет вызываться для объекта, который никак не связан с синхронизированным объектом.

Comment: Сам список заказов изменяется параллельно? Заказы добавляются/удаляются?

Comment: Вам нужны банальные striped locks

Comment: @Regent, можно ли как-то улучшить мой механизм или следует просто перейти на стнхронизированную реализацию?

Comment: @defaultlocale, да.

Comment: @etki, как я понял, это блокировки определнных частей списка и `ConcurrencyHashMap` работает как раз по такому принципу?

Comment: Нет, это вообще никак не связано с конкретными коллекциями. Это просто набор локов, блокирующих определенную полосу работы.

Comment: Хотя с тем условием, что это HashMap, лучше даже сразу взять ConcurrentHashMap, потому что локи здесь все равно не будут гарантировать корректность выполнения

Comment: @etki, решение найдено, посмотрите ответ.

Comment: @Regent, решение найдено, посмотрите ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации к классу [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), оказывается (удивительно, что для такой частой проблемы уже придумали решение :)), есть готовое решение в виде метода [compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-), который принимает функцию и выполняет ее атомарно с блокировкой!